# How to implement code first with existing database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using entityframework 5 with code first model and existing database.I am implementing repository pattern.I have  a BaseEntity class like below:

```
 public abstract partial class BaseEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the entity identifier
        /// </summary>
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as BaseEntity);
        }

        private static bool IsTransient(BaseEntity obj)
        {
            return obj != null && Equals(obj.Id, default(int));
        }

        private Type GetUnproxiedType()
        {
            return GetType();
        }

        public virtual bool Equals(BaseEntity other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return false;

            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
                return true;

            if (!IsTransient(this) &&
                !IsTransient(other) &&
                Equals(Id, other.Id))
            {
                var otherType = other.GetUnproxiedType();
                var thisType = GetUnproxiedType();
                return thisType.IsAssignableFrom(otherType) ||
                        otherType.IsAssignableFrom(thisType);
            }

            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            if (Equals(Id, default(int)))
                return base.GetHashCode();
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static bool operator ==(BaseEntity x, BaseEntity y)
        {
            return Equals(x, y);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(BaseEntity x, BaseEntity y)
        {
            return !(x == y);
        }
        protected virtual void SetParent(dynamic child)
        {

        }
        protected virtual void SetParentToNull(dynamic child)
        {

        }

        protected void ChildCollectionSetter<T>(ICollection<T> collection, ICollection<T> newCollection) where T : class
        {
            if (CommonHelper.OneToManyCollectionWrapperEnabled)
            {
                collection.Clear();
                if (newCollection != null)
                    newCollection.ToList().ForEach(x => collection.Add(x));
            }
            else
            {
                collection = newCollection;
            }
        }


        protected ICollection<T> ChildCollectionGetter<T>(ref ICollection<T> collection, ref ICollection<T> wrappedCollection) where T : class
        {
            return ChildCollectionGetter(ref collection, ref wrappedCollection, SetParent, SetParentToNull);
        }

        protected ICollection<T> ChildCollectionGetter<T>(ref ICollection<T> collection, ref ICollection<T> wrappedCollection, Action<dynamic> setParent, Action<dynamic> setParentToNull) where T : class
        {
            if (CommonHelper.OneToManyCollectionWrapperEnabled)
                return wrappedCollection ?? (wrappedCollection = (collection ?? (collection = new List<T>())).SetupBeforeAndAfterActions(setParent, SetParentToNull));
            return collection ?? (collection = new List<T>());
        }
    }
```

Now I have a table Customer which has CustomerId as primary key  .How should I map such like fields with Id of BaseEntity.If I have a composite key how should I map this to the BaseEntity ID.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the initialize for your DBContext to false:

context.Database.Initialize(false);

Here is a good article on database initializers for code first:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm